# How to display this colon format of emoticons in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, emoticons

I can not display this format (`:fearful::stuck out tongue::persevere::sweat:`) of emoticon using Ionic 3.

When I use this format, it can not turn them into an emoticon, it always remains in plain text, why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you mean "emoji", rather than "emoticons"? This is an emoticon: :-) and this is an emoji: 

Comment: I need to display emoticons and even emoji when needed, because when I send an emoticon, it just displays the raw text and in case I receive an emoji, it displays a blank message.

So I do not know how to display that in ionc 3.
Thanks for your help.